# Pentaho Server: Changes made in the report does not reflect in the Pentaho Server (User Console)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am working on a pentaho report and am able to publish it in the server. However, I would like to know how to automatically get the reports in the server refreshed, when I make some changes in the report using report designer.

Also, I am manually starting the pentaho server everytime. Is there a way to configure the pentaho server to start during system boot up itself???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. We need to open the Pentaho User Console and then

Click on Home -> Click on Administration -> Under Users & Roles, click on '+' next to Users -> Create a User and give the roles as Business Analyst (any role will work)

Now, click on Browse files and place the pentaho report .prpt file under the newly created user folder, click on the report and then click on Run in Background.

Log out of the Pentaho user console Admin credentials, Log in again with the User credentials in the console and open the report as a web page. Go to the report designer, change or edit some values, and then refresh the web page in the user console, you can see the changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to tools-> refresh -> refresh report catch(reporting catch) ..
Ideally it get refreshed every few minutes automatically but if you want to do it whenever you want you have to follow above steps.

Comment: I am trying to publish my reports in a html format. Its a project in which there are multiple reports and all the reports has to be connected to real time data source and the users need to click on the report link to see the report. Any way we can achieve this???

Comment: This is a another question... still answer to your question is yes possible, you can check for sub-report concept..

Comment: What I meant is how can I connect Pentaho User Console with real time data??? I update my pentaho report file (report.prpt) by adding some rows or columns but I dont see the changes getting reflected in the pentaho user console where the report is saved.